# How does server density monitor their servers?

Tags: monitoring

If server density is a monitoring service, then how do they monitor their own servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Server Density itself for most of our monitoring but also make use of other tools so if we suffer an outage, we can be notified and can still pull up graphs to figure out what happened. For this we use New Relic, Pingdom and Aware Monitoring. This also has the side benefit of using competitor tools so we can help improve our own product too.

Comment: Thanks, you guys have a great product! Changed the way I work.